# How to stop RMI server programmatically and notify all clients

Tags: java, rmi

I have developed an RMI application where the RMI server has to be started several times and also has to stop several times.

- How can I stop the RMI server without closing the application?
- How do I send notifications to all clients that the server is going to stop?

Comment: Upvoted unexplained downvote. However the question would be better expressed in standard English.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with the "RMI server", the RMI registry you cannot stop programmatically. But you can stop your service (bound to the RMI registry). You should invoke a custom method to cleanly shutdown your service and then `unbind`it from the registry.

Before this shutdown and unbinding you should inform all connected clients that the service will be shut down. This notification can be done by callback. Searching for `RMI callback` will give you a lot of examples and tutorials.

Comment: You can stop a Registry you create yourslf via createRegistry(), with UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject().

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to send a notification. Clients of an unexported remote object will get a NoSuchObjectEzception next time they do a remote method invocation on it. They just need to recognize the situation.